# Conditional ordering for sticky posts

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm working on a feature for sticky posts, which can have a `sticky_until`. We want these to show up at the top of the feed until their `sticky_until` has past, then show up in the feed, sorted as if they were regular posts.

For example if I have these five posts and today is 4/10/20

```
new_sticky = {
  text: '1'
  created_at: 4/10/20
  sticky_until: 4/20/20
}

older_sticky = {
  text: '2'
  created_at: 4/5/20
  sticky_until: 4/21/20
}

newish_expired_sticky = {
  text: '3'
  created_at: 4/8/20
  sticky_until: 4/9/20
}

older_expired_sticky = {
  text: '4'
  created_at: 4/1/20
  sticky_until: 4/5/20
}

regular_post = {
  text: '5'
  created_at: 4/7/20
  sticky_until: nil
}
```

I'd want the order to end up

```
new_sticky
older_sticky
newish_expired_sticky
regular_post
older_expired_sticky
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In raw SQL, you would add a conditional to the beginning of your `ORDER BY` clause, causing those posts whose `sticky_until` date hasn't yet occurred to sort first:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN sticky_until >= CURRENT_DATE THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         -- your normal post ordering
```

I'm assuming `sticky_until` is a date, if not you would need to cast it to one.

Comment: Thanks! `ORDER BY CASE WHEN sticky_until >= CURRENT_DATE THEN sticky_until ELSE created_at END desc` ended up doing it for me